# Any Recommendations for Improving this PHP function

Tags: php, function

It's a simple function that takes a zipcode as input, finds the zipcode in the correct array and returns the corresponding city.

```
function zipcode_search($a){

$zip = (int)$a;
//arrays of zipcodes to corresponding cities
$FtMyers = array(33901,33902,33903,33905,33906,33907,33908,33911,33912,33913,33916,33917,33918,33919,33965,33966,33967,33990,33993,33994);
$Naples  = array(34101,34102,34103,34104,34105,34106,34107,34108,34109,34110,34112,34113,34114,34116,34117,34119,34120);
$Cape    = array(33904,33909,33910,33914,33915,33990,33991,33993);
$PtChar  = array(33948,33949,33952,33953,33954,33980,33981,33983);
$Bonita  = array(34133,34134,34135,34136);
$Marco   = array(34145,34146);
$Estero  = array(33928,33929);
$FMBeach = array(33931,33932);
$Sanibel = array(33957);

    if (in_array($zip, $Naples))
        {
            return "Naples, FL";
        }
elseif (in_array($zip, $Marco))
        {
            return "Marco Island, FL";
        }
elseif (in_array($zip, $Bonita))
        {
            return "Bonita Springs, FL";
        }
elseif (in_array($zip, $Estero))
        {
            return "Estero, FL";
        }
elseif (in_array($zip, $FtMyers))
        {
            return "Fort Myers, FL";
        }
elseif (in_array($zip, $FMBeach))
        {
            return "Ft. Myers Beach, FL";
        }
elseif (in_array($zip, $Cape))
        {
            return "Cape Coral, FL";
        }   
elseif (in_array($zip, $Sanibel))
        {
            return "Sanibel Island, FL";
        }
elseif (in_array($zip, $PtChar))
        {
            return "Port Charlotte, FL";
        }
else    {   return "Florida";}  
}
```

I know I can make this better and simultaneously improve the efficacy of it.

Comment: I know this thread is old but you could also use googles geocoding api, sending google a zipcode and returning a json or XML file which you can then parse to get the city. Its free as long as you don't go over 2000 requests per day. You probably have solved this long ago but I figured this may help the next guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Zipcodes change over time, so your function won't be bulletproof. Use a service like strikeiron if you need that.
- You're better off storing a list like this in a database. (Unless you have listed every zipcode that you need to handle. It's just at the cusp of what I'd say should be in a database)

IMHO Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' solution would be difficult to maintain -- there's a lot of copy & pasting going on there. Here's an alternative, which is similar to what you had originally:

```
function zipcode_search($zip){
    $city_zips = array(
        "Naples, FL" => array(34101,34102,34103,34104,34105,34106,34107,34108,34109,34110,34112,34113,34114,34116,34117,34119,34120),
        "Marco Island, FL" => array(34145,34146),
        // etc
    );

    foreach( $city_zips as $city => $zips ){
        if( in_array($zip, $zips) ){
            return $city;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: got a typo, your arg is called $a, but you never check the in_array needle against it ;)

Comment: I'm handling every zipcode I could possibly need in this. Thanks Greg, your solution is definitely what I imagined but could not create.
Can you tell me more about strikeiron?

Comment: @frankV StrikeIron is handy for looking up tax rate information and normalizing addresses for E-commerce sites. It's definitely overkill for this question. They offer several tiers of product; ZIP and Postal Code Information would be the closest to what you're asking about. http://www.strikeiron.com/apps/runapp.aspx?appid=113

Answer (score 2):

```
$pcodes = array(33901 => "Fort Myers, FL", 33902 => "Fort Myers, FL",
  33903 => "Fort Myers, FL", ...);

if (isset($pcodes[$zip]))
{
  return $pcodes[$zip];
}
else
{
  return 'Florida';
}
```

Comment: I was just posting the same! +1

Comment: Too much copy & pasting of city names.

Comment: @Greg: Easily fixed by storing differently and preprocessing.

Comment: Violates DRY. Code is hard to maintain.

Comment: The code doesn't need maintenance. And again, preprocess the data.

Comment: +1 `O(1)` lookup is much more important here than something as irrelevant as code maintenance _in this situation_.

Comment: @nickb I bet there is no measurable performance difference. The data set is WAY too small to care about O(1) vs O(n). In fact, this solution dramatically increases the memory usage, so performance might be worse. It's premature optimization either way. The #1 concern should be code maintenance.

Comment: @Greg Actually, [this method is about 7 times faster in simple testing](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eJNXKa), and that's just with one city. While the numbers might be small now, what happens when maintenance requires adding more zip codes? Your "maintainable" code fails to scale.

Comment: 2 millionths of a second difference per iteration. frankV won't notice. array_fill and array_combine are both O(n), so there's that. Also, I note that you are only handling one city. How will you handle multiple? I tried your solution with array_merge: http://pastebin.com/vfnz0PLg vs http://pastebin.com/ScbjNp9w (0.035s vs 0.011s per 1,000 using the worst case zipcode -- now who is faster:). Finally, as I said in my answer, a database is the right place for this if there is a chance of there being more zipcodes, and that there are other considerations (zip codes changing over time) at scale.

Answer (score 1):

```
function zipcode_search($zip){
    $zip_array['Fort Myers, FL'] = array(33901,33902,33903,33905,33906,33907,33908,33911,33912,33913,33916,33917,33918,33919,33965,33966,33967,33990,33993,33994);
    //... continue....

    foreach($zip_array as $city => $zips){
        if(in_array($zip, $zips)){
            return $city;
        }
    }
}
```